# Prevent android from sleeping in webapp

Tags: android, web-applications

I'm developing a **webapp** that receive notifications from a server. Currently, The target device is only an Android 4 device [a Samsung Galaxy Nexus]). As normal, when the user doesn't touch the screen for a while the screen goes off, lock screen.

I have search in the developers.adnroid.con page, but all i have seen is handling scale, and screen dimensions.

I wouldn't like to make a native app with a webview, because the great thing about a webapp is that it doesn't require installation, and you can just share a link ....

Is there a way to prevent android from sleeping from a webapp **without** using a native app with webview?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a proper solution myself. But playing a video seems to do the trick. So looping a tiny video hidden behind main content should work. You could probably do it using a dataURI for the src for a copy and paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking depends on the android browser.

Or u use a client-side Android application with a webbview or let device save battery with the lock screen :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what i suspected.... It's weird that there are no meta tags or something to say, hey this is a webapp, but i suppose the difficulty is to grant permission over KEEP_SCREEN_ON privileges. Finally i opted for a webview. But if someones knows how to make that work only with web I'm still interested. Any news about a change for Android 4.1?